# Taking a picture of Starlink satellites

Tags: photography

I really want to take pictures of Starlink satellites, but I am fairly new to this kind of photography so I have a few questions. I am using a Nikon d3400 and a tripod obviously.

1. What is the best lens to use and do I need any additional filters?
2. How do I point my camera at the spot where the satellite will pass through, do I need some kind of tracker for it?

Thank you in advance for your answers, I hope my questions made sense.